# Burn several hours of video to DVD using iDVD?

Tags: imovie, idvd

I've got a movie in iMove and I'd like to burn it to DVD. I used the "iDVD" export option in iMovie, but then iDVD refused to burn the DVD on the grounds that the DVD didn't have enough space.

**How do I burn a few hours (~5 GB) of video to a DVD?** I'm okay lowering the quality a bit, if I knew where in iMovie or iDVD to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the easy solution, in iDVD, you have to go to the Project Info Window (`Project|Project Info...` menu) and select a Double-Layer disc in the `DVD Type` combobox.
A single layer disc is 4,2GB and an untouched 5GB movie file will obviously not fit on it.

If you don't have a double-layer capable burner, you will have to first reduce the quality of the video to reduce its size (through the widely used (and easy to use) [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for example), putting the target size to circa 4GB. You will then be able to burn your file with iDVD or any other DVD authoring tool.

iDVD control of video file compression is too simple.
In iMovie, in `Share|Export` You have several size options. Putting the mouse pointer on the little information symbol at the end of each line will give you the approximative size of the output file. I don't know if there is a finer control of output. I usually do it via Handbrake, as stated above.

Comment: Thanks. I actually used Adobe Encore, but your method may work as well. I tried using HandBrake but it kept crashing.

Comment: Quite strange as I am now using it for quite a long time without a single crash. ymmv of course but don't hesitate to post crash logs to developers.